# default shell for remote commands through ssh

Tags: ssh, remote-access

I have the following setup on my ubuntu 10.04 box

```
~$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
~$ grep $USER /etc/passwd
ubuntu:x:1000:1000:Ubuntu,,,:/home/ubuntu:/bin/bash
```

However, when I run a remote command, zsh seems to be the default shell:

```
$> ssh -i /path/to/ssh/key ubuntu@<my-host> "echo $SHELL"
/bin/zsh
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 9):

What you are seeing there is the local login shell.

```
ssh user@host "echo $SHELL"
```

With the above, `$SHELL` is expanded before ssh is run because it's enclosed in double quotes. So on the remote end you're running `echo /bin/zsh` instead of `echo $SHELL`.

Use single quotes to avoid `$SHELL` being expanded locally.

```
ssh user@host 'echo "$SHELL"'
```

See [BashFAQ 96](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/096) for more on this.

Answer (score 1):

You or someone else must have configured your remote host with `zsh`.
To switch back to bash use:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

on your remote host.

Though as an aside I would recommend `zsh` it's an awesome shell with lots of very useful features, and having it enabled doesn't stop you from being able to use bash

```
#!/bin/sh
```

will still run your scripts under bash.

Comment: that doesn't help :( In fact I noticed that chsh thinks that my default shell is bash already (from the 'current value' that it showed to me)

Comment: My only other suggestion would be to look at the key then. You can run forced commands from keys.

Answer (score 0):

read up on login vs non-login shells. my suspicion is that you're doing something funny in `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc`, or `~/.profile`, so check their contents for something that would do this.

Comment: There is nothing that I can find suspicious in the `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` files (there is no `~/.bash_profile` file). Specifically, there is no switch or reference to zsh. Is there anything else that I might be missing? If it helps, this is a ec2 instance using the public AMI: ami-349b495d